# Custom Exception in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, custom-error-handling

I am trying to create a custom error exception in Python. I want the error to be raised if the argument is not in the dictionary `_fetch_currencies()`.

Custom error:

```
class CurrencyDoesntExistError:
    def __getcurr__(self):
        try:
            return _fetch_currencies()[self]
        except KeyError:
            raise CurrencyDoesntExistError()
```

How I have written it into my function:

```
def convert(amount, from_curr, to_curr, date=str(datetime.date.today())):
    """
    Returns the value obtained by converting the amount 'amount' of the 
    currency 'from_curr' to the currency 'to_curr' on date 'date'. If date is 
    not given, it defaults the current date.
    """
    try:    
        from_value = float(get_exrates(date)[from_curr])
        to_value = float(get_exrates(date)[to_curr])

        C = amount * (to_value / from_value)
        return C
    except CurrencyDoesntExistError:
        print('Currency does not exist')
```

I am currently getting the error message:

```
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

If I use `except KeyError:` in my function `convert` it will run but what is the correct way to raise this custom error exception?

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward. If you don't understand it, re-read the python documentation on classes.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a message to print when your exception is raised, do this:

```
class CurrencyDoesntExistError(Exception):
    pass

raise CurrencyDoesntExistError("Currency does not exist")
```

Answer (score 2):

As already said by others you have a problem with your class definition missing the base class reference.

But this can also happen if you have a module and a class with the same name and you import the module rather than the class.

For example module and class are called MyException.

```
import MyException
```

will give you this error, while:

```
from MyException import MyException
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your class definition to:

```
class CurrencyDoesntExistError(BaseException):
    ...
```

The docs: https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance